# Idgenerator laravel 8, how to fix Exception "table field type is bigint but prefix is string"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

why does this message always appear?
even though I want to make an id with 2 dots like = 190772.2021.00000001
can't add '.' (dots) like that can only add 1 dots only 1907722021.00000001
factory.php

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Anggota;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\User;
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;

class AnggotaFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Anggota::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $tgl = $this->faker->date;

        return [
            'id_user' => User::factory(),
            'no_anggota' => IdGenerator::generate([
                    'table' => 'anggotas', 
                    'length' => 19, 
                    'prefix' => date('dmy', strtotime($tgl)).date('.Y.')
                ]),
            'nama_lengkap' => $this->faker->name,
            'tempat_lahir' => $this->faker->cityPrefix,
            'tanggal_lahir' => $tgl,
            'nama_instansi' => $this->faker->word,
        ];
    }
}
```

file migration

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAnggotasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('anggotas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_user')->unique();
            $table->string('no_anggota');
            $table->string('nama_lengkap');
            $table->string('tempat_lahir');
            $table->date('tanggal_lahir');
            $table->string('nama_instansi');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('anggotas');
    }
}
```

whereas column "no_anggota" in the schema database is of type "string" but appears "table field type is bigint but prefix is string"

how to solve it so that the result = 190772.2021.00000001

help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [laravel ID generator](https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-id-generator) package by default use table's `id` column. According to your need, the [documentation says (example 4)](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator), you have to pass `field` also.

Your required output: 190772.2021.00000001 ( length 20 with two dots)

**Solution**: Just pass `'field' => 'no_anggota'` and `'length' => 20`

```
$tgl = $this->faker->date;

$idConfig = [
    'table' => 'anggotas',
    'field' => 'no_anggota',
    'length' => 20,
    'prefix' => date('dmy', strtotime($tgl)).date('.Y.')
];

return [
    'id_user' => User::factory(),
    'no_anggota' => IdGenerator::generate($idConfig),
    'nama_lengkap' => $this->faker->name,
    'tempat_lahir' => $this->faker->cityPrefix,
    'tanggal_lahir' => $tgl,
    'nama_instansi' => $this->faker->word,
];
```